Disable page break until everything is printed. Print from website
I am using react-to-print with Nextjs.
Problem

This is the problem.
I don't want it to break and want it to continue and treat it as 1 page.
I have POS-80C thermal printer, and it cuts on every page.
It should only cut at the last when everything is printed.
Things I tried
- I tried to use page-break inside @media print .
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 80mm auto;
    margin: 7.56px;
  }

  .dontsplit {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    // page-break-before: avoid;
    // page-break-after: avoid;
    page-break-after: always;
  }

  .table-to-print * {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .no-print {
    display: none;
  }
}

- I tried scaling it down to fit on a single page, but the text becomes very tiny and unreadable.
resize-page-contents-to-fit-on-one-print-page
Questions
- Is it fixable with CSS only?
- Is it fixable with javascript before .print() is initialized?
- Is it the default behaviour of browsers and can't be fixed?

Seems that your @page size auto has been translated into 297mm (see screenshot). Can you use an explicit length like 1000cm?

@HeikoTheißen changing auto to 100 cm or 1000cm causes the text to shrink/scale down. Precisely, the margin becomes too much, and when I make the margin of left and right to 2mm same thing as the picture happens.

Does it help if you "Print > Save as PDF ..." first and then print the PDF instead of the HTML page?

@HeikoTheißen That makes it worse. I saved it in pdf as A4 (there is no option for 80mm). When I open the pdf, and print from the printer, the text are overflowing. Only the S.N. and order (left side of the bill) is seen on the paper.

Sorry, I meant save as PDF without specifying @page size. This gives me a PDF document with one very long page.

Its still giving me 2 pages even if I remove the size. But is I set my size to 100cm, it comes in a long paper in pdf. Which is what I want, but when I select my printer, it again prints 2 pages, or if I select a long form 80 x 3276, it only prints like 4cm of the printer paper and the text are like dots.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I believe what you need is to do is to add overflow: visible to the .dontsplit class. or you could add the page-break-inside: avoid; overflow: visible; to the body, html CSS and then create a class to simulate the page break, for example: .pagebreak { page-break-before: always; }
